# How can i get value of one particular row from the previous row (if exists) in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
 Table name couponDetail.
 Current Values in `couponDetail` table;
 Here couponCode is unique field with status Active.
 Means its not possible for two couponCode to exists with same 
 name and 'Active' status`enter code here.

 -----------------------------------------------
|id  |  couponCode | status | Date     | offer  |
|-----------------------------------------------
|1  | First       | Inactive| 3rd jan  | 20% off|
|2  | Second      | Inactive| 4th jan  | 30% off|
|3  | First       | Inactive| 5th jan  | 10% off|
|4  | Second      | Inactive| 5th jan  | 40% off|
|5  | Second      | Active  | 6th jan  | 50% off|
|6  | First       | Active  | 7th jan  | 15% off|
------------------------------------------------

Desired output :-

 -----------------------------------------------
|id  |  couponCode | status | Date     | offer  |
|--------------------------------------|---------
|5  | Second      | Active  | 3rd jan  | 50% off|
|6  | First       | Active  | 4th jan  | 15% off|
------------------------------------------------
```

Need only date value from the old row(If exists otherwise fetch the date which is in that new row) other values are needed to be fetched from the newly created rows.

I have to do this task using query only no stored procedures

Comment: What do you mean by old and new row and I don't see a relationship between the id and date in your desired output.

Comment: CouponCode is unique so cant we fetch the value from that couponcode field??

Comment: Also old row and new row means, initially i was giving 20%off on using couponCode 'FIRST' which i created on 3rd jan. But then i updated the offer and changed from 20% to 10% on 5th jan. So a new row is created after marking the first row as inactive and so on i have made changes in the offer field for coupon 'FIRST'

Comment: Odd defintion of unique..Also FIRST was created on 3rd Jan and second was created on 4th Jan (apparently) - using First and Second as coupon name is distracting try using something more real.

Comment: Actual structure is slightly different from this one. I just want to fetch the value of field 'Date' from the inactive row(If exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to want most recent paired with first.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T
(id  INT,  couponCode VARCHAR(20), status VARCHAR(20), Date VARCHAR(20), offer VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1  , 'First'       , 'Inactive' , '3rd jan'  , '20% off'),
(2  , 'Second'      , 'Inactive' , '4th jan'  , '30% off'),
(3  , 'First'       , 'Inactive' , '5th jan'  , '10% off'),
(4  , 'Second'      , 'Inactive' , '5th jan'  , '40% off'),
(5  , 'Second'      , 'Active'   , '6th jan'  , '50% off'),
(6  , 'First'       , 'Active'   , '7th jan'  , '15% off');


SELECT T.*,
        (SELECT DATE FROM T T1 WHERE T1.COUPONCODE = T.COUPONCODE ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1)   DT 
FROM T

WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM T T1 WHERE T1.COUPONCODE = T.COUPONCODE);

+------+------------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| id   | couponCode | status | Date    | offer   | DT      |
+------+------------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|    5 | Second     | Active | 6th jan | 50% off | 4th jan |
|    6 | First      | Active | 7th jan | 15% off | 3rd jan |
+------+------------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```